# Angular directive: how to call a function that's defined in 'controller' from appended html string in 'compile'

Tags: angularjs

Given the following HTML

```
<a>
   Link Text
</a>
```

I want to make a directive that appends a html code that calls a function to display something in angular.

```
baseModule.directive('a', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function ($element) {
            $element.append('<span class="inner-class">{{displaySomething()}}</span>');
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.displaySomething = function () {
                 return 'something';
            }
        },
    };
});
```

So in **'compile'**, I appended the html with **{{displaySomething()}}**. Which doens't show the content. If use **'template'** here instead of compile then it would work. But I can't do that because that would wipe out the **Link Text**. Can someone guide me to the right direction?

Comment: working for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/xaLtjHdxmtZF2EskbcF5?p=preview